# How to create box-shadows simulating multiple depths

Tags: html, css, shadow, box-shadow

Say I want to simulate 2 different layers of objects, over a background. Objects on the first level should have a large shadow, and objects on the second layer should have a smaller shadow.

Now, what if an objects on the front layer is overlapping an object on the second layer? Then it should have a large shadow on the background, but a smaller shadow on the second layer object.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

[image: A picture of 2 overlapping objects, as described above.]

Can this effect be achieved with CSS? Even SVG filters, or something like that maybe? Any ideas?

Comment: Plain old CSS. Check out some source code, materialize, for instance: http://materializecss.com/shadow.html

Answer (score 2):

you may use a pseudo to increase part of a shadow:

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin: 3em;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
}
p {
  margin: 2em;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  background: white;
}
p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 265px;/* offset value to mind */
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #333;
  pointer-events:none; /* takes it off the way, else negative z-index might do also */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

size, margin and padding for demo purpose, use real content :)